# How does Mockito mock a insert method of returning primary key using myBatis

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

`ServiceImpl` class has an `add()` method using Mybatis `insert()` return “isSuccess Tag” and auto record the `User` object's id，when mock `add()` method using Mockito, we can't get user id value and `NulPointerException` occurs.

```
 public class ServiceImpl{
        public int add() {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setName("uName");
            UserDao userDao=new UserDao();
            userDao.add(newUser);  //Using myBatis insert() method,and it function is auto assign user.Id and return completed row number.     
            int userId = newUser.getId();
         }
    }

        //methodTest
        public class ServiceImplTest
        {
            @Test
            public void addTest()
            {
              UserDao userDao=Mockito.mock(UserDao.class);
              when(userDao.add(isA(User.class))).thenReturn(1);//NullPointException in newUser.getId();
              ServiceImpl serviceImpl=new ServiceImpl();
              serviceImpl.add();
            }
        }
```

How to solve the problem?
Thaks

Comment: Do you understand what mocks are used for? You can't mock the same method which you are testing

Comment: Sorry,I had fixed code and edited question again but stil NullPointException.Because mybatis' insert() method auto assign userId,but return number of rows completed.I can not mock the assignment in insert method by thenReturn() .What should I do？

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the mocked object and specifically call the `add` function on that mocked object. Otherwise you're not using the mock:

```
@Test
public void addTest() {
    ServiceImpl serviceImpl = Mockito.mock(ServiceImpl.class);
    when(serviceImpl.add()).thenReturn(1);
    serviceImpl.add();
}
```

Edit: Also you can't mock a function with a signature that doesn't exist. So I've removed `User.class` from the `when(serviceImpl.add())` call.

Comment: Sorry,I find wrong code.I had reedited question and posted it.stil NullPointException.because mybatis' insert() method auto assign userId,but return number of rows completed.We can only mock method return value and can not mock the assignment by thenReturn() .

Answer (score 0):

```java
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setName("uName");
when(UserDao.add(newUser)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public User answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
    User newUser1 = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(0,User.class);                   
    newUser1.setId(1);
    return 1;
  }
});
```